# Microsoft bot framework unable to validate credentials in skype configuration

Tags: frameworks, bots, skype

I am developing a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework, I can test it from the "my bots" section and it is working fine but when I add it to skype it simply doesn't answer, I go to the "configure skype (https://skype.botframework.com/)" section in the MS Bot framework and in the 5th step says "Unable to validate the given credentials.", I am not sure if the skype Bot Id and App Id are the same key? or where do i find them? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes skype bot ID and App ID is same.

1. First create a bot in [Application Registration Center](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) as an
   application.
2. After you create new application you can find Both Application ID and Application secret from there where you can enter in you 5th step.
3. Before that got to [skype bot management portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/manage) and create your bot with same application Id you had generated before.
4. Finally don't forget to add message calling back URL for the bot as in configuration page.

Then you are ok to go with your Skype bot. Cheers!

Comment: The "Application secret" is what i get when I click on "generate new password"?